# Can the Epson V700 be used with an Airport Extreme and an HDD at the same time?

Tags: wireless-networking, osx-snow-leopard, time-machine, scanner, airport-extreme

I have a MacBook Pro, Snow Leopard, an Epson V700 Scanner and a standard external 1TB Hard Drive used for Time Machine.

I'm thinking of buying an Airport Extreme.

Two questions:

1. Can I use the Epson V700 via the Airport Extreme as if it was connected locally via USB?
2. If so, can I plug both the Scanner and the HDD into the Aiport Extreme via USB?

cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that you can scan over Airport..

> Note: AirPort Base Station and Time Capsule printer sharing is for printing only, not for printer utilities or other special features that may require a direct proprietary connection.
>   http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1253

You can, however, connect a printer and a USB drive to an Airport Extreme using a USB hub, and you can share your scanner (and printer) over the network when its connected to a Mac via USB.  See
[Sharing your scanner](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/28021.html).